# Mel - spectogram size

Tags: python, neural-network, signal-processing, voice-recognition, librosa

I am extracting a log Mel - spectrogram from the GTZAN dataset using Librosa in python. My code -

```
data, sampling_rate = librosa.load(os.path.join(dir, folder, file), )
mel = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=data, hop_length = 512//2, n_fft = 512, n_mels = 64)
mel = librosa.power_to_db(mel**2)
```

Well, It works perfectly. But, the size of each Mel-spectrogram is different. Most of the log Mel-spectrogram having a size of 2586, a few of them having 2590 to 2620.

I checked the size is different when taking the log on Mel-spectrogram. How they differ in size when taking the log were all audios are in the same length...

Any suggestion, thanks

Comment: Probably you corrupted the files somehow. You'd better show the full code

Comment: Actually, It is the full code, The above three lines of codes are in a for loop to get the file name. Then load it using librosa and converted to melspectrogram and take log. 1st audio have a length of 2586 after convertion but 2nd audio have a length of 2590.

Comment: I do not know what is the issue... Could you please give any idea to resolve...

Comment: Start with providing a complete and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example